# How to dynamically update certain dictionary value in file using python

Tags: python

I have file , which contain below data [ *It is not Dictionary* ]

```
{'name':'Raju','surname':'XYZ','age':13,'dateofjoin':'12-Jul-2017'}
```

**Note :** My file contain only one record

My issue is how to update the value for `age : 13` to `18` and `dateofjoin` : `12-Jul-2017`  to `15-Aug-2008` in file

**My code with error :** `io.UnspportableOperation not writeable`

```
v='age'
b=18
dt='dateofjoin'
dtvalue='15-Aug-2008'

with open('demo.txt','r') as fr:
    m=fr.readline()
    createdictionary=ast.literal_eval(m)
    d[v]=str(b)
    d[dt]=str(dtvalue)

    fr.write(d[v],d[dt])
```

**Below is the expected output need to be override the existing line with updated value**

```
{'name':'Raju','surname':'XYZ','age':18,'dateofjoin':'15-Aug-2008'}
```

Comment: `open('demo.txt','r') ` opens the file as read only

Comment: You should use open('demo.txt','r+') to be able to write to the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening your file as `r` for reading. You can't write to a file that's opened for reading.

You'll want to do something like this (though it would be better to use JSON rather than a `repr` of a dict.)

```
import ast

with open('demo.txt', 'r') as fr:
    # Read and parse data.
    data = ast.literal_eval(fr.read())

# Modify data.
data['age'] = 18
data['dateofjoin'] = '15-Aug-2008'

# Open the file for writing and write the data.
with open('demo.txt', 'w') as fw:
    fw.write(repr(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `r` mode opens up a file in **read-only** mode. To open a file for reading an writing, use `r+`

```
with open('demo.txt','r+') as fr:
```

### See [Files I/O methods in python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation)

How ever, as rightly mentioned by @AKX, if the new representation of the data is shorter than the original, itwill overlapp the file.

In that case:

Truncate the whole file before writing into the file.

```
fr.seek(0)
fr.truncate()
```

Comment: Using `r+` in this case is problematic in that if the new representation of the data is shorter than the old one, the program will need to remember to truncate the file in order to avoid `{"foo": "bar"}ar"}`.

Comment: Oh, and you'd also need to `.seek()` to the start of the file, if you're using the same handle. Otherwise the new object is written after the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping [ Contributor : [AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx) and [Sujay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15801675/sujay) ]

I was able to write code by taking your inputs

Below is the way i tried and it work for me

In case any suggestion or update required in code , feel free to edit it

**My code :**

```
import ast

path_names ='C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\JUL'
print(path_names)

file_nme= path_names + '\\' + 'demo.txt'

agenames='age'
agevalues='10'

dtnames='dateofjoin'
dtvalues='18-JAN-2021'

with open(file_nme,'r+') as dr:
    read_first_record=dr.readline()

    #Storing to dictionary
    dictvalues=ast.literal_eval(read_first_record)
    print('Previous data of file : ',dictvalues)

    #Truncating file data
    dr.seek(0)
    dr.truncate()

    #Writing updated data
    dictvalues[agenames]=agevalues
    dictvalues[dtnames]=dtvalues
    print('Updated data of file : ',dictvalues)
    dr.write(str(dictvalues))
```

**Previous data in file :**

```
{'name':'Raju','surname':'XYZ','age':13,'dateofjoin':'12-Jul-2017'}
```

**After running code, below is the updated data in file  :**

```
{'name': 'Raju', 'surname': 'XYZ', 'age': '10', 'dateofjoin': '18-JAN-2021'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the outer side of the source code, and also find these automatically you can use something like this (via [refactor](https://github.com/isidentical/refactor));

```py
import ast
import refactor
from refactor import Rule, ReplacementAction

class ReplaceValue(Rule):
    
    REPLACEMENTS = {'age': 10}

    def match(self, node):
        assert isinstance(node, ast.Dict)
        
        for index, key in enumerate(node.keys):
            if isinstance(key, ast.Constant) and isinstance(
                value := node.values[index], ast.Constant
            ):
                key_v, val_v = key.value, value.value
                if key_v in self.REPLACEMENTS and val_v != self.REPLACEMENTS[key_v]:
                    return ReplacementAction(
                        value, 
                        ast.Constant(self.REPLACEMENTS[key_v])
                    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    refactor.run(rules=[ReplaceValue])
```

When you run it, it will either produce a diff;

```
 $ python z.py q.py
--- q.py

+++ q.py

@@ -3,6 +3,6 @@

 
 {
     'name':'Raju',
-    'surname':'XYZ', 'age': 13, # maybe comments
+    'surname':'XYZ', 'age': 10, # maybe comments
     'dateofjoin':'12-Jul-2017'
 }
All done!
1 file reformatted
```

or can apply these changes

```
 $ python z.py -a q.py
reformatted q.py
All done!
1 file reformatted
(.venv39) (Python 3.9.0) [  5:22ÖS ]  [ <hey>@<hey>:/tmp ]
 $ cat q.py
def some():
    stuff()

{
    'name':'Raju',
    'surname':'XYZ', 'age': 10, # maybe comments
    'dateofjoin':'12-Jul-2017'
}
```